# Автор последнего сообщения VK API

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю бота для ВК на Node.js. Немогу получить ID автора последнего сообщения конференции.
Возвращает undefined. Не понимаю почему

```js
'use strict';

(o) => {

    let comp = ['заворожуючий','сексі','шикарний','такий звабливий','красавчик','креативний','романтичний','солоденький','загадковий','бездоганний','скромняга','привабливий','незрівнянний','феєричний','самий-самий',];
    
    var lenComp = comp.length - 1;
    var choise = parseInt((Math.random() * (lenComp - 0 + 1)) + 0);
    
    var gans = comp[choise];
    
    
  o['$'].callMethod('messages.getHistory', {offset: 1, count: 1, peer_id: 2000000112}, (ans) => {
    try {
        ans = JSON.parse(ans)['response']['items'];
        o['bot'].send(`&#127823; ${['user_id']}`, o['body'], {});
    } catch(e) {
      o['bot'].send('Команда працює тільки в конференціях', o['body'], {});
    }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: так может нет там еще сообщений `items` вот и `undefined`

Comment: если в тестирую запрос этими же параметрами в документации VK. Все ок.